What is the best way to sync I/O audio streams to mix them in real-time?
I want to mix loopback stream with audio from microphone in real-time and use the result of mixing for speech recognition.
The project is for Windows, so I use WASAPI and am willing to know what is the best option in my case? Now I have two streams that I should feed to the mixer and send result to the ASR model.
The streams are both in the same format. How is this real-time syncing done in the professional audio software internally? Appreciate the answers!

Hi and welcome. Can you elaborate what exactly needs to be synced and why? If this is about clock management, the window's kernel mixer can handle that.

Hi, thanks! I want to mix two streams in real-time: one is from microphone (IAudioCaptureClient) and another is from the specific process (ActivateAudioInterfaceAsync). I need to do that, because they are not aligned (data from one stream is coming faster, than from the other). Also I want to know what "pattern" is used in this situations, I mean I have two circular buffers for each stream and two threads are running (mic capturing and loopback capturing), how should I trigger the third thread to mix those streams, so there is no tangible delay. What is the common approach in general?

Sorry, I still don't get it. A block diagram with signal flow and clock domains would help here. Are you saying the speech is  both on the microphone and loopback channel and needs to be time aligned ?
